# Bootstrapped Pattern Extraction Method Error while I tried patternScoring=LOGREG

Tags: stanford-nlp

I would like to try a pattern extraction method by using Stanford CoreNLP 3.6.0 on Ubuntu.
It worked as a default setting (through patterns/example.properties) by running Pattern Extraction method as follows:

```
java -mx1000m -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.patterns.GetPatternsFromDataMultiClass -props patterns/example.properties
```

However, when I changed the Pattern Scoring setting in the example.properties to "patternScoring=LOGREG", I encountered an error as follows:

```
Cannot assign option field: java.lang.Class edu.stanford.nlp.patterns.ScorePhrases.phraseScorerClass value: edu.stanford.nlp.patterns.ScorePhrasesLearnFeatWt; invalid type
java.lang.RuntimeException: [Ljava.lang.Object;@466dd2b7
  edu.stanford.nlp.util.logging.Redwood$Util.runtimeException(Redwood.java:973)
  edu.stanford.nlp.util.Execution.fillField(Execution.java:243)
  edu.stanford.nlp.util.Execution.fillOptionsImpl(Execution.java:477)
  edu.stanford.nlp.util.Execution.fillOptionsImpl(Execution.java:536)
  edu.stanford.nlp.util.Execution.fillOptions(Execution.java:599)
  edu.stanford.nlp.util.Execution.fillOptions(Execution.java:603)
  edu.stanford.nlp.patterns.ScorePhrases.<init>(ScorePhrases.java:50)
  edu.stanford.nlp.patterns.ScorePatternsRatioModifiedFreq.convert2OneDim(ScorePatternsRatioModifiedFreq.java:198)
  edu.stanford.nlp.patterns.ScorePatternsRatioModifiedFreq.score(ScorePatternsRatioModifiedFreq.java:89)
  edu.stanford.nlp.patterns.GetPatternsFromDataMultiClass.getPatterns(GetPatternsFromDataMultiClass.java:1318)
  edu.stanford.nlp.patterns.GetPatternsFromDataMultiClass.iterateExtractApply4Label(GetPatternsFromDataMultiClass.java:2310)
  edu.stanford.nlp.patterns.GetPatternsFromDataMultiClass.iterateExtractApply(GetPatternsFromDataMultiClass.java:2124)
  edu.stanford.nlp.patterns.GetPatternsFromDataMultiClass.runNineYards(GetPatternsFromDataMultiClass.java:3330)
  edu.stanford.nlp.patterns.GetPatternsFromDataMultiClass.run(GetPatternsFromDataMultiClass.java:3310)
  edu.stanford.nlp.patterns.GetPatternsFromDataMultiClass.main(GetPatternsFromDataMultiClass.java:3611)
Cannot assign option field: edu.stanford.nlp.patterns.ScorePhrases.phraseScorerClass value: edu.stanford.nlp.patterns.ScorePhrasesLearnFeatWt cause: [Ljava.lang.Object;@466dd2b7
java.lang.RuntimeException: [Ljava.lang.Object;@3cfb55fe
        at edu.stanford.nlp.util.logging.Redwood$Util.runtimeException(Redwood.java:973)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.util.Execution.fillField(Execution.java:257)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.util.Execution.fillOptionsImpl(Execution.java:477)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.util.Execution.fillOptionsImpl(Execution.java:536)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.util.Execution.fillOptions(Execution.java:599)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.util.Execution.fillOptions(Execution.java:603)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.patterns.ScorePhrases.<init>(ScorePhrases.java:50)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.patterns.ScorePatternsRatioModifiedFreq.convert2OneDim(ScorePatternsRatioModifiedFreq.java:198)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.patterns.ScorePatternsRatioModifiedFreq.score(ScorePatternsRatioModifiedFreq.java:89)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.patterns.GetPatternsFromDataMultiClass.getPatterns(GetPatternsFromDataMultiClass.java:1318)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.patterns.GetPatternsFromDataMultiClass.iterateExtractApply4Label(GetPatternsFromDataMultiClass.java:2310)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.patterns.GetPatternsFromDataMultiClass.iterateExtractApply(GetPatternsFromDataMultiClass.java:2124)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.patterns.GetPatternsFromDataMultiClass.runNineYards(GetPatternsFromDataMultiClass.java:3330)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.patterns.GetPatternsFromDataMultiClass.run(GetPatternsFromDataMultiClass.java:3310)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.patterns.GetPatternsFromDataMultiClass.main(GetPatternsFromDataMultiClass.java:3611)
```

Does someone know how to fix this problem?

Thanks,